# E: Package 'mpich2' has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu, mpich

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed (Xenial release). I need to install the mpich2 package onto my system, but when I run `sudo apt-get install mpich2`, it gives me the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mpich2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mpich:i386 mpich

E: Package 'mpich2' has no installation candidate
```

I think the mpich2 package belongs to the Trusty release of 14.04 Ubuntu version but I need the mpich2 package only for my work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and after a challenging search process I ended up with installing **mpich2** from source. Basically the process includes these :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install gfortran
cd /tmp
wget http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/1.4.1/mpich2-1.4.1.tar.gz
tar xzvf mpich2-1.4.1.tar.gz  
cd mpich2-1.4.1/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Above are the necessary commands for a successful build.
After these steps you can check your installation with:

```
mpich2version
```

and if you get an output like this:

```
MPICH2 Version:     1.4.1
MPICH2 Release date:    Wed Aug 24 14:40:04 CDT 2011
MPICH2 Device:      ch3:nemesis
MPICH2 configure:   
MPICH2 CC:  gcc    -O2
MPICH2 CXX:     c++   -O2
MPICH2 F77:     gfortran   -O2
MPICH2 FC:  f95   -O2
```

viola you are done.
You can take a look at [this](http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/1.4/mpich2-1.4-installguide.pdf) guide. For newer version check [here](http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/).

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, you can just install MPICH instead of MPICH2. Originally, the MPICH project was named MPICH, then when version 2 was released, the name was changed to MPICH2. When they made it to version 3, they went back to the original MPICH name.

Comment: It means that `sudo apt-get install mpich` will solve Madhur Aggarwal's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed if you change mpich2 for mpich works.

$ mpichversion
MPICH Version:      3.3a2
MPICH Release date: Sun Nov 13 09:12:11 MST 2016
MPICH Device:       ch3:nemesis